# Is cleanliness next to Godliness?

Tags: catholicism, cleanliness

I've been ardently searching the Bible for a proverb my wife keeps quoting. But somehow, I don't think it is in there.  So, where did the notion that being clean had anything to do with being holy?  I like to tell my wife that only my feet need to be clean (I know where that is in the Bible).

Looking for historical answers from a Catholic tradition or if it really is in the Bible that would be good too. What I'd really like to know is how clean is clean enough not to be a slothful slob and how clean is so clean that you miss out on the "better part" that Jesus said Martha was missing out on.

Comment: I think that saying cleanliness is next to godliness   does not imply  that cleanliness is, necessarily,  part of godliness. Godliness is the most important priority, but after that comes cleanliness. It is effectively saying that cleanliness is the most important earthly  thing, while acknowledging that religious obligations are of course even more important.

Comment: Isaiah 1:16-18 tells us to wash and be clean

Comment: googling seems to hint that John Wesley coined the phrase 'cleanliness is indeed next to godliness' in 1778 or Sir Francis Bacon in 1605 with 'cleanliness of body was ever deemed to proceed from a due reverence to God'

Comment: Actually it was until 1983,when Dorkiness and Loch Ness pushed it out of the way.

Comment: @dep that is awesome ifbthe quote is really from Wesley. That really makes my day.  Gonna tell my wife right now, lets see if I get slapped.

Comment: @depperm Bacon's wording makes me think he was referring to more of an Old Testament usage of "clean". Like, no fornication and that kind of thing.

Comment: @fredsbend I realize that, just pointing out potential origins of the phrase

Comment: Not sure why one is seeking a Catholic answer to a Protestant aphorism, but it's worth asking.   The monasts and hermits established a long tradition of not bathing while trying to get closer to God.  Are you sure the term refers to "physical" cleanliness rather than "spiritual" cleanliness?  @depperm I think you've got the meat of the answer. Nice work.

Comment: @korvin I'm asking because my wife is convinced she's read it in the Bible - everything is a muddle in America and I'd be delighted if it was some sort of Protestant maxim. However, I think I remember being taught that Harry Houdini's mother had a similar maxim.  (If you grow up in Wisconsin there is a whole semester devoted to Harry Houdini).   She said that "God invented poverty, but he didn't invent dirt" and my own mother claimed that God's invention of forks had something to do with me not being a slob, so I think there is some element of Catholicity in the saying.

Comment: Peter, oh dear, syncretism of folks adages with Catholic teaching!  A burning at the stake seems to be in order, because nobody expects the Madison Inquisition!  Cardinal Fang will be along shortly with a comfy chair.

Comment: @korvin and yet the powers that be will not let me start a [new site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110376/christian-living) to ask these kinds of garbage questions.

Comment: Peter, it never hurts to ask.  I think @depperm has most of an answer if he chooses to move what's in comments into an answer.

Comment: @PeterTurner "Jesus answered, 'Unless I wash you, you have no part with me.'" (John 13:8) The reason Jesus was only washing feet was "Those who have had a bath need only to wash their feet; their whole body is clean." In case you can't tell, this is a tongue-in-cheek comment. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking for the origins of the quote there are two possibilities:

Sir Francis Bacon in 1605 in [Advancement of Learning](http://oll.libertyfund.org/titles/bacon-the-advancement-of-learning#toc) mentions

> For cleanliness and decency of the body were always allowed to proceed from moral modesty and reverence; first, toward God, whose creatures we are; next, toward society, wherein we live; and lastly, toward ourselves, whom we ought to reverence still more than others.

John Wesley in [On Dress](http://wesley.nnu.edu/john-wesley/the-sermons-of-john-wesley-1872-edition/sermon-88-on-dress/)  mentions 'cleanliness is indeed next to godliness' in 1791.

See also [Phrase Meaning and Origin](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/5/messages/1209.html) or a similar question on [English SE.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/44135/229008)

Answer (score 2):

The [ceremonial precepts of the Old Law](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS099.html#FSQ99A3THEP1) included ritual washings not because cleanliness was the end sought in an of itself but because the ceremonial precepts were meant to teach the ancient Israelites of a spiritual reality, such as sin (dirtiness) and the purity (cleanliness) resulting from God's forgiveness.

In the New Law, [only the sacramental aspect of baptism is a mere washing](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP066.html#TPQ66A1THEP1).

Answer (score 1):

Isaiah 52: 11:

> Depart ye, depart ye, go ye out from thence, touch no unclean
>   thing; go ye out of the midst of her; be ye clean, that bear the
>   vessels of the Lord.

This can be interpreted symbolically, but that really doesn't help you much.

On the other hand, you can always ask her (nicely) to take it easy about judging your ideas of what is important. (Matthew 7, if it's not on the tip of your tongue:)

> Judge not, that ye be not judged.

But remember, it's a two-edged sword:

> For with what judgment ye judge, ye shall be judged: and with what
>   measure ye mete, it shall be measured to you again.

You have to be careful how you judge your wife's attempts to help you be a better person.